# Retrieving images in React from a protected backend folder

Tags: react-native, .htaccess

I'm working on a React-app in which I would like to show the avatar of the logged in user. I retrieve all the user-information from my PHP backend, so i know the url of the image i want to show. The images however, are stored in a private folder which is protected with a `.htaccess` file.

Because of privacy reasons, the images-folder needs to remain private, so the images can't directly be accessed. I was thinking about converting the image with base64 encoding and passing it through the api, but this doesn't feel like a correct solution. Is there a way to retrieve the images from the private folder, by authenticating myself in any kind of way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: _“by authenticating myself in any kind of way?”_ - not _you_ need to authenticate yourself, the user’s browser has to. So unless you want to make the credentials available on the client side (which, of course, you don’t, otherwise the whole “protection” would be pointless to begin with), there is no way.

Comment: Users have to login when opening the app, so they are already authenticated. I'm just wondering how i can tell the .htaccess that my React application has access to the folder

Comment: _“so they are already authenticated”_ - then what’s the problem? Can not really make sense of your explanation here.

Comment: How do you currently access the _other_ images that are "protected with a `.htaccess` file"? (Presumably you mean by HTTP (basic?) Authentication?) Should the avatars of other users be accessible as well or users can only see their own avatar?

Comment: The folder with images is located in the main application. In the main application, logged in users receive a cookie which is checked by the .htaccess. Once a user is logged in, he can see other avatars aswell. The .htaccess just checks for the cookie, so only logged in users can see the images and they are not directly accessible in a browser.